# SQL rawQuery if contains

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

A quick question, I can't find it on the internet, probably I am looking at the wrong "term".
But how do you make a SQL query statement with "`if contains`"

```
"SELECT something FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE name **contains** '*String*'", null);
```

I know you got these statements: `=` `>` `<` `>=` `<=` but what to use for `if contains`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `LIKE` keyword

Depending on the variety of SQL for the wildcard.

```
...Where name like '%string%'
```

SQLite uses % for a sequence of 0 or more unspecified characters (like a *), and an underscore _ for any single character

Comment: @ruffin I didn't aat first :)

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT something FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%spam%'`

(percent signs act like asterisks in a "conventional" search, give or take.)

You can get much more complicated with dbms specific functions (eg, [here's Oracle's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html)) that can, situationally, add regular expressions and other ways of searching.

As always, watch out for collation issues and case.

Answer (score 2):

you can use LIKE

```
"SELECT something FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE name like '%yourstring%'";
```

refer to: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of   "if contains" you can use the "like" statement...

the query will be...

```
"SELECT something FROM tablename where name like %'string'%"
```

This will return what u want,,,

For Example:
Your table name "abc" contains Jarry,Jack,John,Josh,.....
if u run the query

select * from abc where name like %Ja%

it will return

Jarry,Jack..